# Save array to binary file not working c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an unsigned char array in c++, and I want to save it's bits into a file.

So for example if I have the array below

```
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
arr[2] = 2;
```

I want to save this into the file so that the binary data of the file looks like this (without the spaces).

```
00000000 00000001 00000010
```

I have tried this code below but it doesn't seem to work. I give the program a blank file that is 0 bytes in size, and after the program runs the file remains 0 bytes in size (nothing gets written to it).

```
// Create unsigned char array
unsigned char *arrayToWrite= (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*720);

// Populate it with some test values
arrayToWrite[0] = 0;
arrayToWrite[1] = 1;
arrayToWrite[2] = 2;

// Open the file I want to write to
FILE *dat;
dat = fopen("filePath.bin", "wb");

// Write array to file
fwrite(&arrayToWrite, sizeof(char)*720, 1, dat);
fclose(dat);
```

I would expect after this program runs that the file "filePath.bin" would be 720 bytes long filled with mostly 0's except for the first and second position I filled with test data.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does your `malloc` clear the memory, or just allocate it? This is how you leak sensitive information if you're not careful. You're also not checking for errors on your file operations, so you may be missing something there. `errno` will be set on failures.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" adding wrong tags first. Second -expecting that malloc would zero initialize memory.

Comment: `&arrayToWrite` is the address of the pointer `arrayToWrite`; the call should be made with the address of the data that it points at.

Comment: remove the `&` character, arrayToWrite is already a pointer

Comment: For c++ use `std::vector`

Comment: @tadman Thank you for telling me this! Wow I had no idea malloc didn't clear the memory. Sorry I'm very new to c++, yes I understand. Do  you suggest I use calloc instead as suggested by Sneftel's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue there is that you're passing the pointer to your `arrayToWrite` variable, rather than to the array itself. Change `fwrite(&arrayToWrite...` to `fwrite(arrayToWrite...`.

BTW, `malloc()` does NOT promise to give you zeroed memory. For that, use `calloc()` to allocate and zero memory or `memset()` to zero already-allocated memory. (Though all that is more a C thing; for C++ you'd be better off using something like `std::vector` instead of raw C arrays.)

Comment: I think that the first paragraph is irrelevant to his question because there's no difference between passing arrayToWrite or & arrayToWrite.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense, sorry I didn't realize the answer was so easy as I'm very new to c++. That extra bit of info regarding calloc vs malloc though was also very helpful.

Comment: @Harald you are wrong in this case passing `&arrayToWrite` is very different

Comment: @Harald There wouldn't be, if `arrayToWrite` had array type, but it has pointer type so the two are not equivalent.

Comment: @YAHsaves you provided not C++ code, if you want to learn C++ do not write C code, it will be more difficult to relearn

Comment: @slava why? These are all pointers pointing at the same data.

Comment: @Harald adress of a pointer variable is not the same as the pointer itself, even has different type, `unsigned char **` it works because both can convert to `const void *` but that is issue of `void *`

Answer (score 3):

C++ code is written different way:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vectorToWrite = { 0, 1, 2 };
vectorToWrite.resize( 720 );
std::ofstream file( "filePath.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
if( !file ) {
    // error handling
}
file.write( vectorToWrite.data(), vectorToWrite.size() * sizeof( decltype(vectorToWrite)::value_type ) );
```

Note: I put `sizeof( decltype(vectorToWrite)::value_type )` there so if you later change vector data it will still properly work without further change, but in case of `char` it can be omitted completely as `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1

Comment: I agree, but whooof, `decltype(vectorToWrite)::value_type` is not putting C++'s best foot forward. ;)

Comment: @Sneftel yea in case of `char` it can be omitted as `sizeof(char)==1` by standard but there are so many pedanting downvoters